# Array of select values

Tags: php, html, arrays, drop-down-menu

So basically, I have an array of Modules and I want to have a drop-down menue that users can then select what grade they got. This works fine, however, I would like the results to be stored inside of an array, to however many values they selected. So for example:

If someone selected "40" in Mod1 and in Mod2 they selected "20" then the array would be like this:

mod1=>40

mod2=>20

...

Here is the code so far, it's probably something stupid, I just cannot get my head around it.

```
<?php

$modules = array('Mod1', 'Mod2', 'Mod3');   

if(!isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
    echo '<form method="post">';

    echo 'Please enter the grades you got for each Module: <br />';
    foreach($modules as $module)
    {
        echo $module . ': <input type="text" name="grades[]" value=""> <br />';
    }
    echo '<br /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE">';

}else{

    $input = $_POST['score[]'];
    foreach($modules as $i => $module){
        $input[$module] = $input[$i];
        var_dump($input[$module] = $i);
        //unset($input[$i]);
    }
    //var_dump($input);

}

?>
```

Comment: do not put tags in subject http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a name that groups the values of the `select`s in `POST` into one array:

```
echo '<select name="score[]">';
```

You can then use:

```
$input = $_POST['score[]'];
foreach($modules as $i=>$module){
    $input[$module] = $input[$i];
    unset($input[$i]);
}
var_dump($input);
```

Comment: Thank you. But this shows as "array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "90" [1]=> string(2) "12" [2]=> string(2) "23" }" whereas I want it to be... [Mod1]=> string(2) "90" etc.. How would I do that? Do I need to map the array?

Comment: Thanks, but this puts the array now as: "array(3) { ["Mod1"]=> NULL ["Mod2"]=> NULL ["Mod3"]=> NULL }" I don't know why it's giving NULL

Comment: @Phorce What happens when you try it without the `unset`?

Comment: @Phorce Strange. Try this and tell me what the output is: `$input[$module] = $i;`

Comment: I get "int(0) int(1) int(2)" I have updated my code in my original post

Comment: @Phorce Are you even selecting anything?

Comment: No, I changed the code so you have to type something now.. I've also changed so that it is named correctly, still get NULL.

Comment: Got it :) Thank you so much for your help. Sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="score[<?php echo $module; ?>]">
```

should get you going :)
the array will look exactly like you narrowed it down in the intro.

Answer (score 1):

just change your name attribute to an array:

`echo '<select name="score[]">';`

the the $_POST variable will be in an array

Comment: Thanks :) It worked! I knew it was something silly. Could you tell me also, why it only shows "Mod1", "Mod3" from my array.. "Mod2" seems to have just disappeared.

Comment: it appears that you don't have a closing `</select>`